# How to change some items in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using `natbib` package and `jtbnew` bibliography style. I would like to ask you some questions.

1. How can I change output and instead of abbreviation *ed.* get *edition*?
2. How can I change output and instead of abbreviation *vol*. get *volume*?
3. How can I write the author name *Øksendal*?

Comment: Can you point to a source for `jtbnew.bst`?

Comment: @egreg: The file's on the CTAN under /bibliography/bibtex/contrib/misc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you look at the jtnew.bst (which is the file specifying the styling of the bibliography), you'll find e.g. the following

```
FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "ed." }
```

This tells BibteX what it should print when you need an "edition". Change that into

```
FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edition" }
```

And you get the change "ed." -> "edition".

You do the analogous thing for the volume:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "vol." }
```

becomes

```
FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "volume" }
```

Øksendal can be written in a few ways. You either have Unicode support (by using XeTeX, LuaTeX or input encoding settings), but BibTeX is not really Unicode aware, so you would have to use BibTeXu (which I never tried).

The other way is to simply write `{\O}ksendal`.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding your third question: Write the name as `{\O}ksendal`. Encasing the "special" marks in curly braces is also the preferred method in BibTeX for diacritics (Umlaute, e.g., `{\"a}`), accented letters (e.g., `{\'e}` and `{\’u}`), and other composite characters such as the `c` with a cedilla or `r` with a háček ("v-check").

Regarding your first two questions: Make a copy of the file `jtbnew.bst` and call it, say, `myjtbnew.bst`. Open the new file in an editor, search for all instances of `ed.` (likely in the function `bbl.edition`) and `vol.`, and replace them with your preferred alternatives. Save the file, update the tex file name database if necessary, and be sure to include the directive `\bibliographystyle{myjtbnew}` in your documents.